# Is "As and when…" correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, american-english

> As and when the user scrolls the page ...

Is this correct English?
The context is: A person is describing scrolling on the web page.
Not sure if the "As and" part is correct or it adds any extra meaning to the sentence. Instead of saying "As and when" one could say "when the user scrolls the page..." will it mean the same thing?

Comment: It's a kind of sloppy speech that shouldn't get past a copyeditor. It is *probably* inspired by "if and when", which is more common.

Comment: I don't think it's "sloppy". Maybe [it's not quite as common as **if and when**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+and+when%2Cif+and+when&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), but semantically and syntactically I see no problem with it. On the other hand, ***if and when*** is definitely a bit "weird" on the semantic front. We don't often say ***if OR when***, but logically that would make more sense!

Comment: The grammar is technically acceptable, but the usage is wrong and the style is terrible. Just use one or the other

Comment: Did you look up the meanings of "as" and "when" (as you're using them here)? Are the meanings similar or different?

Answer (score 1):

The [most common context](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20and%20when%20required%2Cif%20and%20when%20required&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for the collocation ***as and when** X* is in "imperative" statements and similar (giving advice / permission / ...) where X defines the *conditions* when the advice / permission applies...

[image]

Note that most of the above matches will be in imperative contexts like ***Take one of these pain killer tablets** as and when required*. The construction is less common in contexts like OP's (as and when *an action is being performed*), but it's still perfectly natural to *this* native speaker.

The difference between using *both* terms (when either on its own should be sufficient) is simply a nuance of emphasis. You can understand ***as and when*** as carrying the sense of ***every time, whenever***.